# "@angular/core/testing"' has no exported member 'waitForAsync'

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to import waitForAsync from '@angular/core/testing'. I am getting this error:

Module '"@angular/core/testing"' has no exported member 'waitForAsync'.ts(2305)

Any idea why?

Comment: What version of Angular

Answer (score 2):

**waitForAsync** only exists since Angular v10.
It comes to replace **async**.